# Python logging - wrapper

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am new to writing utility functions. I wrote a python program to return a Python logger with custom settings. Please review this code and provide comments on how to improve it. I am looking for comments on

1. Coding Style
2. Coherence & Coupling
3. Readability

I am intending to share this code across all projects. So any comments on this to improve are highly appreciated.

```
import logging
import sys
import logging.handlers


def get_default_log_format():
    """ Method to return the default log format"""
    log_format = logging.Formatter("%(module)s - %(asctime)s — %(name)s — %(levelname)s - %(funcName)s:%(lineno)d — %(message)s")
    return log_format


def get_new_console_handler(log_format=None):
    """This method returns a console handler with the given log_format
        Keyword Arg: log_format accepts logging.Formatter object.
    """
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    if log_format is None:
        log_format = get_default_log_format()
    console_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
    return console_handler


def get_new_file_handler(log_format=None, log_file_name="out.log"):
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file_name)
    if log_format is None:
        log_format = get_default_log_format()
    file_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
    return file_handler


def get_new_rotating_file_handler(log_file_name="out.log", max_log_bytes=2000000, max_log_backup_files=20, log_format=None):
    """ This method returns a file handler with the given file name, max_log_bytes, max_log_backup_files and log_format. This log_format accepts logging.Formatter object"""
# Here, max_log_bytes is the maximum size of file in Bytes and max_log_backup_files is the number of backup files to store.
    file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(log_file_name, maxBytes=max_log_bytes, backupCount=max_log_backup_files)
    if log_format is None:
        log_format = get_default_log_format()
    file_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
    return file_handler


def get_new_console_logger(logger_name, log_format=None, log_level=logging.DEBUG):
    handler = get_new_console_handler()
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(log_level)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger


def get_new_file_logger(logger_name, log_file, log_format=None, log_level=logging.DEBUG):
    handler = get_new_file_handler(log_format, log_file)
    if log_file is None:
        log_file = "execution.log"
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(log_level)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger


def get_new_file_console_logger(logger_name, log_file, log_format=None, log_level=logging.DEBUG):
    if log_file is None:
        log_file = "execution.log"
    logger = get_new_file_logger(logger_name, log_file)
    console_handler = get_new_console_handler()
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)
    return logger


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # To get a console handler, run this code
    console_logger = get_new_console_logger(logger_name="logger1")
    console_logger.debug("Hello World")

    # To get a file logger, run this code
    file_logger = get_new_file_logger(logger_name="logger3", log_file="out.log")
    file_logger.critical("This is a critical message")

    # To get a console and file logger, run this code
    console_file_logger = get_new_file_console_logger(logger_name="my_logging2", log_file="out3.log")
    console_file_logger.error("Error: This is from console file logger")


    # logger.info("Begining of execution")
    # logger.info("logging Info message")
    # logger.debug("This is a debug message")
    # logger.debug(logging.DEBUG)
    # logger.info(logging.INFO)
    # logger.warning(logging.WARNING)
    # logger.error(logging.ERROR)
    # logger.critical(logging.CRITICAL)
    # logger.info("End of Execution")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### *Restructuring and consolidation*

*Logging configuration*

When having a *constant* logging options like posted `log_format` or `log_level=logging.DEBUG` you might have been used [`logging.basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) or even [`dictConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) to apply specified options globally to all underlying cases.
But since your intention is to allow the client create different specialized *loggers* with dynamic logging options, *"base"* config won't give much benefit. At least, it's good to remind of such a *base configuration* capability.

---

*Handlers*

All 3 handlers run the same common set of statements to ensure *logging format*:

```
if log_format is None:
    log_format = get_default_log_format()
console_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
```

That calls for consolidation and reducing duplication.
Moreover, when creating some concrete logger instance a client may pass `log_format` as a raw format string like `log_format='%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d — %(message)s'`, not as `logging.Formatter` instance. Thus, for further optimizations I'll eliminate `get_default_log_format` function and declare a constant:

```
LOG_FMT = '%(module)s - %(asctime)s — %(name)s — %(levelname)s - %(funcName)s:%(lineno)d — %(message)s'
```

According to the scenario where the client/caller operates only on `.._logger` functions to instantiate concrete loggers, that points to direct relation between specific *logger* and respective *handler*(s). And assuming that duplicated common code should be moved out from all handlers - they ceased *pulling their weigh* and are removed in favor of direct handler usage. See the final implementation below.

---

*`..._logger` functions*

*"logger"* creation functions perform a common set of actions:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
logger.setLevel(log_level)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

that also calls for consolidation.
The condition

```
if log_file is None:
    log_file = "execution.log"
```

is eliminated by simply making `log_file` a default argument **`log_file="execution.log"`**.

---

To perform consolidation and reducing duplication a *factory* function **`logger_factory(logger_name, handlers_list, log_format, log_level)`** is introduced. It concentrates a common behavior and also allows to attach multiple *handlers* to the same *logger*.

The final optimized version:

```
import logging
import sys
import logging.handlers

LOG_FMT = '%(module)s - %(asctime)s — %(name)s — %(levelname)s - %(funcName)s:%(lineno)d — %(message)s'


def logger_factory(logger_name, handlers_list, log_format, log_level):
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(log_level)

    if not isinstance(handlers_list, (list, tuple)):
        handlers_list = [handlers_list]
    for handler in handlers_list:
        handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(log_format))
        logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger


def create_console_logger(logger_name, log_format=LOG_FMT, log_level=logging.DEBUG):
    return logger_factory(logger_name, handlers_list=[logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)],
                          log_format=log_format, log_level=log_level)


def create_file_logger(logger_name, log_file="execution.log", log_format=LOG_FMT, log_level=logging.DEBUG):
    return logger_factory(logger_name, handlers_list=[logging.FileHandler(log_file)],
                          log_format=log_format, log_level=log_level)


def create_rotating_file_logger(logger_name, log_file="out.log", max_log_bytes=2000000, max_log_backup_files=20,
                                log_format=LOG_FMT, log_level=logging.DEBUG):
    """ Creates rotating file logger with the given file name, max_log_bytes, max_log_backup_files and log_format.
         :param log_file: log file name
         :param max_log_bytes: the maximum size of file in Bytes
         :param max_log_backup_files: the number of backup files to store
         :param log_format: custom format as logging.Formatter object
         :param log_level: logging level
         :return: logging.Logger
     """
    handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(log_file, maxBytes=max_log_bytes,
                                                   backupCount=max_log_backup_files)
    return logger_factory(logger_name, handlers_list=[handler],
                          log_format=log_format, log_level=log_level)


def create_file_console_logger(logger_name, log_file="execution.log", log_format=LOG_FMT, log_level=logging.DEBUG):
    handlers = [logging.FileHandler(log_file), logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)]
    return logger_factory(logger_name, handlers_list=handlers,
                          log_format=log_format, log_level=log_level)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # To get a console handler, run this code
    console_logger = create_console_logger(logger_name="logger1")
    console_logger.debug("Hello World")

    # To get a file logger, run this code
    file_logger = create_file_logger(logger_name="logger3", log_file="out.log")
    file_logger.critical("This is a critical message")

    # To get a console and file logger, run this code
    console_file_logger = create_file_console_logger(logger_name="my_logging2", log_file="out3.log")
    console_file_logger.error("Error: This is from console file logger")
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It helped me :)

Comment: @Mithilesh_Kunal, you're welcome